# Why are Cloud Function Errors Not Reported in Error Reporting Dashboard?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-stackdriver, google-cloud-error-reporting

In our Stackdriver logs, some functions are failing due to:

`Error: memory limit exceeded. Function invocation was interrupted.`

I easily solved the problem by deploying functions with more memory.

However the real problem is that these errors did not appear in the Error Reporting Dashboard: https://console.cloud.google.com/errors

Why do memory limit errors not appear in the Error Reporting Dashboard?

What other errors are not being reported?

Is this a bug that should be escalated to Google?

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55851399/12265927), this kind of exceptions (memory exceeded) are *Application-wide uncaught exceptions* and they should be reported manually by the [code](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-error-reporting#catching-and-reporting-application-wide-uncaught-errors).

My suggestion is to catch this kind of exceptions to be reported in the *Error Reporting Dashboard* and just to complement the errors, you can create a metric in *Stackdriver Monitoring* to check the behavior of the function and have a more friendly view of the function's behavior.