# Error when deploying google cloud function - run out of memory?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage, cloud, bucket

I have used the following deployment for the example code used in the tutorial for a google cloud function. The function should simply print the statements below when a new item is added to my bucket, (which happens every half hour)

Example code (file is also called hello_gs.py):

```python
def hello_gcs(event, context):

    print('Event ID: {}'.format(context.event_id))
    print('Event type: {}'.format(context.event_type))
    print('Bucket: {}'.format(event['bucket']))
    print('File: {}'.format(event['name']))
    print('Metageneration: {}'.format(event['metageneration']))
    print('Created: {}'.format(event['timeCreated']))
    print('Updated: {}'.format(event['updated']))
```

I deploy it with:

```
gcloud functions deploy hello_gcs \
--trigger-resource bucket1 \
--trigger-event google.storage.object.finalize
```

I get the following error in my logs

```
insertId: "000000-f7b8ac5b-61f2-4d37-902a-b21ab56372c9"
labels: {1}
logName: "projects/project-name-v2/logs/cloudfunctions.googleapis.com%2Fcloud-functions"
receiveTimestamp: "2021-10-20T11:38:19.093774441Z"
resource: {2}
severity: "ERROR"
textPayload: "Function cannot be initialized. Error: memory limit exceeded.
"
timestamp: "2021-10-20T11:38:18.112056018Z"
```

and yet the function is so simple and small I find this hard to understand?

Any ideas what I am doing wrong here, and help would be appreciated.

Comment: check this to gather more info https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54667666/google-cloud-functions-memory-limit-exceeded

Comment: You haven't specify the runtime of your function. Are you sure to have shared all the paremeters with us?

Comment: Could you please give us some more information from [your logs](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/overview)? 

Most probably your project ran out of memory, which happens often if you are using free/low quotas for learning purposes. Maybe you'll need to delete temporary files to free memory.

Comment: It feels weird that your file is named `hello_gs.py` when [the docs say explicitly that your file must be named `main.py`](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing#functions-writing-file-structuring-python).